# Spellcheck in LEd editor

Tags: spelling, led-editor

I'm writing a paper and have some problems with the LEd editor. I need to do a spellcheck (english) and the editor seems to have one built-in. When I click on spellcheck (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>) it says "end of spellchecking", without doing it. Can you give me advice how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Open `Configuration->Options`, go to the `Spellchecking->Dictionaries` tab and make sure that `English (United Kingdom)` or `English (United States)` is selected in the `main dictionary` dropdown box. (If *it is already selected*, choose another language as main language temporarily, then revert to English.) After clicking `OK`, the spell checker should work correctly.

[image]